# How to import protobuf well-known types in AspNet Core gRPC Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, protocol-buffers, grpc

I', scratching my head about how to import "google/protobuf/empty.proto" to my proto file. What I'm doing so far:

1. In my .csproj file, I added the following:

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

      <PropertyGroup>
         <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
         <Protobuf Include="C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\google.protobuf.tools\3.10.0\tools\google\protobuf\*.proto" GrpcServices="Server"/>
         <Protobuf Include="Protos\*.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
      </ItemGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
         <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.23.2" />
         <PackageReference Include="System.Reactive" Version="4.1.6" />
      </ItemGroup>

   </Project>
   ```
2. In my project folder, I have a folder called "Protos" where I have a test.proto file in which I would like to use the "empty.proto" like:

`import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";`

However, I get the error `File not found in project`. I also do not like to specify the "3.10.0" in the `ItemGroup`. What is the correct way to use google protobuf well-known types?

Answer (score 6):

Well known protos (such as empty.proto) actually get special handling in the Grpc.Tools package - the import path for well known .proto files is added automatically and the generated code is already part of Google.Protobuf itself.

They only thing you need to do in your proto file is to add:

```
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
```

and after then you can use google.protobuf.Empty type in messages normally. No other steps are needed.

Comment: Do you happen to know why it has red squiggles in VS editor? I've got latest Google.Protobuf, Grpc.Core and Grpc.Tools installed. It's a class library.

Comment: OK responding to myself: it was the ReSharper. After disabling support for Protobufs in ReSharper everything's fine. I think I'll uninstall it altogether, it creates more issues than it solves...

Answer (score 5):

if you are using resharper just follow the pic

[go to r# option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzYvq.jpg)

[uncheck the selected protobuf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjQGX.jpg)

reason of this issue :
Though Protobuf is purely path-based and will work once the file in found on your hard disk ReSharper needs all the files added to solution in order to process them and Current implementation of included files' search inside protobuf support does not allow to find the files outside the solution.

have good time