# How do you import the google.type.Money type in an aspnetcore project using Grpc?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, protocol-buffers, grpc, currency

I have an aspnetcore application that's using Grpc, and is currently working fine with a simple message containing only strings.

I need to add a new message that will contain money values, and I saw that there is a money.proto type available by importing google/protobuf. However, when I try to import it, I get an error.

I added the following in my proto file:

```
import "google/protobuf/money.proto";
```

I expected the Grpc Money type to be generated during the build, and complete successfully.

However, the build fails and I get the following errors:

```
Import "google/protobuf/money.proto" was not found or had errors.
"google.protobuf.Money" is not defined
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58258997/how-to-import-protobuf-well-known-types-in-aspnet-core-grpc-service) question asked previously, and the answer was to disable protobuf support in ReSharper. However, when I checked this setting, the box was already unchecked by default, as shown below:

[image: resharper-protobuf-setting-disabled]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58796851/8422356) follow-up comment stated that these proto files are available in the Grpc.Tools nuget package, which I have installed in my project:
[image]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66478429/grpc-import-google-proto-cannot-resolve) similar question had the same answer.

I was able to find the file itself on github [here](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/type/money.proto), and used it to confirm that I had the casing correct (import statement lower-case m, type usage upper-case M). I noticed that the package for this file was 'google/type' and not 'google/protobuf', so I tried changing my import statement and usages to match, but it had no effect on the problem, same errors.

I checked [here](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis) to see if there was any documentation on how to get this working, and all they had to say was this:
[image]

Which, if I'm reading it correctly, suggests that if I have a working Grpc setup, then I should have this available.

Finally, I found [this](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2020/01/16/grpc-well-known-types.aspx) article suggesting that these files must be manually copy/pasted into your project, but that seems quite primitive? Surely there's a way to pull these in automatically through nuget or something?

I've been unable to find any further guidance on the topic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a .NET developer but I am familiar with Google|gRPC. It's confusing and poorly-documented (!). [`money.proto`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/type/money.proto) is part of Google's [Common Types](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google/type) **not** part of Google's [Well-Known Types](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf) and so it's not included with [`Grpc.Tools`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Tools/), and is **not** `google/protobuf/money.proto` but should be `google/type/money.proto`

Comment: Because the common types are used by Google's APIs, `money.proto` is referenced by Google's API Client for .NET (NuGet [`Google.Apis`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis)) and by its extensions library (NuGet [`Google.Api.Gax`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Api.Gax/4.1.1) and [`Google.Api.Gax.Grpc`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Api.Gax.Grpc/)) but these include the C# code generated by protoc for the common types **not** the proto which you need. In short, I'm unsure whether Google publishes a NuGet package that includes the protos for its common types.

Comment: Thank you for making clear the distinction between common types and well-known types, that's very helpful. I looked into the Google.Apis packages on nuget and found one called CommonProtos that seemed promising, but after installing it the result was that the Money type in the package conflicted with my locally generated one, but the import statement in the proto still complained that the proto file couldn't be found. I'm going to keep hacking away at it and get a github repo put together to get it documented once I figure it out.

Comment: You're welcome. Hopefully someone else has trodden this path and can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies it's taken me this long to get back with an update, but I believe I've got it all sorted now.

The tl;dr is that I needed to do the following to fix the problem:

1. Install the [Grpc.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.AspNetCore#readme-body-tab) nuget package in both the server and the client.
2. Add the [googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google/type) repo as a git submodule.
3. Add a <Protobuf Include="../path/to/money.proto" /> item element in both the client and server project files.
4. Add the AdditionalImportDirs attribute to the <Protobuf /> item element for "my" proto file so it can import the money proto file.

Server csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Proto\example.proto" GrpcServices="Server" AdditionalImportDirs="..\..\BuildingBlocks\googleapis" />
    <Protobuf Include="..\..\BuildingBlocks\googleapis\google\type\money.proto" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Client csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="../GrpcExample.Server/Proto/example.proto" GrpcServices="Client" AdditionalImportDirs="..\..\BuildingBlocks\googleapis" />
    <Protobuf Include="..\..\BuildingBlocks\googleapis\google\type\money.proto" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I've created a github repo with an example client/server project that shows working code on how to set this all up, and a README that walks you through step-by-step how to go from 2 web API projects to Money working over gRPC.

[example-grpc-aspnetcore](https://github.com/hexsorcerer/example-grpc-aspnetcore)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and tried out some different permutations. This one does the job:

```
import "google/type/money.proto";

message MyMessage {
  google.type.Money money = 1;
}
```